# PHPMailer throwing an error looking for PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception which isn't in my code?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Need some help with PHPMailer code. Error from log is below which appears on send of form. Have read all of the posts referencing this same error but my issue is different as I am not allowed to use Composer on my hosting company's shared server. I am following a manual install of the files.

Here's the log file error:

```
[18-Dec-2018 22:30:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' not found in /home1/example/public_html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php:1720
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/example/public_html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1518): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->mailSend('Date: Tue, 18 D...', '<html>".$feedba...')
#1 /home1/example/public_html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1352): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend()
#2 /home1/example/public_html/adoption/sendEmailTest.php(22): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home1/example/public_html/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 1720
```

Here's the code from lines 1719-1721, but this file is OOB for PHPMailer:

```
if (!$result) {
            throw new Exception($this->lang('instantiate'), self::STOP_CRITICAL);
        }
```

Here's my php file code:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require '../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->setFrom('myname@example.org', 'Org Name');
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('myname@example.org', 'Org Name');

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Application Submission';  
    $mail->Body = '<html>".$feedback."</html>';

    if (!$mail->send())
    {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}

?>
```

Here's the form code so you have it:

```
    <form action="sendEmailTest.php" method="post" name="adoption">

        <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><h2><strong>Form Test</strong></h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="183"><label>Name: </label></td>
                <td width="496"><input name="name" type="text" required="required" id="name" value="" size="75" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Email Address: </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" size="75" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Feedback</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="feedback" id="feedback" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" name="submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>     
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you both! Going to throw them back in and give it a try BUT I'm not currently using the exception or smpt classes in my code, which is what confused me. I followed this article that said if I'm not using them, to remove them?

"If you prefer not to use exceptions, just omit the argument (or set it to FALSE). In this case you need to check the send() method return value and look for the error message in the $ErrorInfo attribute:"

https://alexwebdevelop.com/phpmailer-tutorial/

Comment: Tutorial 0, @KirkBeard & Don't Panic 1... I added them back in and error has gone away. Have a new error now (Could not instantiate mail function) but need to research it as it's a new one for me. Thanks to you both!

Comment: @CinderGirl You're welcome! I added some explanation to my answer to address your comments here. Hopefully it will help alleviate some of the confusion. :-)

Comment: It’s not true that you can’t use composer in that context. You may not be able to run it on your server, but you can run it locally and upload the vendor folder it creates along with the rest of your code. The readme describes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be missing the required classes at the start.

Your example includes:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
```

You need to add:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

This should solve the PHP errors you mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using autoloading, you'll have to require and use any classes used in your code.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
```

Regarding your comment on the question, you aren't using Exceptions in your code, but the PHPMailer class uses them internally. Leaving the exceptions argument of the controller empty does not disable PHPMailer exceptions altogether. If you look through the source you'll see some places where `throw new Exception...` is wrapped in `if ($this->exceptions) { }`, and other places where it will throw them regardless.

The exception you got after adding the require/use statements isn't really a new problem, it's the exception that was originally trying to be thrown when you got the "class not found" error.